OpenCV AruCo detection fails: "Embedded video playback halted; module v4l2src0 reported: Failed to allocate required memory."
I've been trying to run a simple AruCo detection code on my Raspberry Pi 4B, and consistently get the error "Embedded video playback halted; module v4l2src0 reported: Failed to allocate required memory". I am brand new to raspberry Pi's, and also not very experienced in python and thus have never seen this error. Looking online provided no answers. Any help would be appreciated. The code is below. Thanks in advance.
import cv2 as cv
from cv2 import aruco
import numpy as np 

# dictionary to specify type of the marker
marker_dict = aruco.getPredefinedDictionary(aruco.DICT_5X5_250)

# detect the marker
param_markers = aruco.DetectorParameters()

# utilizes default camera/webcam driver
cap = cv.VideoCapture(0)

# iterate through multiple frames, in a live video feed
while True:
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    if not ret:
        break
    # turning the frame to grayscale-only (for efficiency)
    gray_frame = cv.cvtColor(frame, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    marker_corners, marker_IDs, reject = aruco.detectMarkers(gray_frame, marker_dict, parameters=param_markers)
    # getting conrners of markers
    if marker_corners:
        for ids, corners in zip(marker_IDs, marker_corners):
            cv.polylines(
                frame, [corners.astype(np.int32)], True, (0, 255, 255), 4, cv.LINE_AA
            )
            corners = corners.reshape(4, 2)
            corners = corners.astype(int)
            top_right = corners[0].ravel()
            top_left = corners[1].ravel()
            bottom_right = corners[2].ravel()
            bottom_left = corners[3].ravel()
            cv.putText(
                frame,
                f"id: {ids[0]}",
                top_right,
                cv.FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN,
                1.3,
                (200, 100, 0),
                2,
                cv.LINE_AA,
            )
            print(ids, "  ", corners)
            if (ids == 0):
                print("0")
    cv.imshow("frame", frame)
    key = cv.waitKey(1)
    if key == ord("q"):
        break
cap.release()
cv.destroyAllWindows()


Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
